# Postman : Reading inputs from csv data file and iterating through each row and form the request body based on mandoty & optional parameter

Tags: javascript, json, csv, postman, multiple-input

I have a csv file like below. Where in row1 all the headers value are passed and in the 2nd row countryId is null since it optional.

```
userName,password,address1,countryId
test1,pass1,lblr,1
test2,pass2,
```

When i read the csv file in postman pre-request i am getting output as below.

```
userName: "roxxroyce"
password: "Pass@123"
address1: "LBLR"
countryId: 1

userName: "roxxroyce"
password: "Pass@123"
address1: "RQIP"
```

Tried the below code login to achieve the expected output. But this seems to be not giving the correct results. Can someone help me with this request?

```
let lines = iterationData.split('\n');
let headers = lines[0].split(',');
let requestBodyArray = [];

for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    let values = lines[i].split(',');
    let userObject = { user: {} };

    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length && j < values.length; j++) {
        let key = headers[j].trim();
        let value = values[j] ? values[j].trim() : ''; // Check if value exists before trimming

        if (value !== "") {
            if (key === "countryId") {
                // Add countryId to the address object
                if (!userObject.user.address) {
                    userObject.user.address = [{ [key]: value }];
                } else {
                    userObject.user.address[0][key] = value;
                }
            } else if (key === "address1") {
                // Add address1 to the address object
                if (!userObject.user.address) {
                    userObject.user.address = [{ [key]: value }];
                } else {
                    userObject.user.address[0][key] = value;
                }
            } else {
                // Add other properties to the user object
                userObject.user[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    requestBodyArray.push(userObject);
}

// Log the resulting request body
console.log(JSON.stringify(requestBodyArray, null, 2));
```

Expected output:

iteration#1:

```
  {
    "user": {
      "userName": "test1",
      "password": "pass1",
      "address": [
        {
          "address1": "lblr",
          "countryId": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

iteration#2:

```
      {
        "user": {
          "userName": "test2",
          "password": "pass2"
        }
      }
```

Comment: What is being returned by your code and what is wrong with the results.

Comment: The code which i tried is returning a empty result. @mikee

Comment: Actually the csv data is read during the postman runner where i upload the input data file . I am using let iterationData = data ; to read the csv data and the output is returned in key-value pair. I need to iterate through the data and form the request body based on mandatory and optional parameters. @mikee